# How do I go through a file with spacers and get an array to output in Bash?

Tags: bash

Here's my current code, the idea was to get details from a text file, split it up with the truncate, and output text in a readable way.

patron.txt only has this line:

```
123456:Gerald:010-9999999:asdf@gmail.com
```

The idea was for to make an array with 4 parts, each read individually, and input into the echo one by one.

The terminal instead is just showing a blank line.
I heard printf can do the trick but I dunno how to make heads or tails with that, at least in bash.

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "Search Patron Details"
echo -n "Enter Patron ID: " 
read id1
grep -i -q "$id" patron.txt

array=$(echo $id | tr ":" "\n")

for fill in $array
do
$loop++
 if [$loop == 0]
 then
  :
 elif [$loop == 1]
 then
  echo "Fullname (auto display): $fill"
 elif [$loop == 2]
 then
  echo "Contact Number (auto display): $fill"
 elif [$loop == 3]
 then
  echo "Email Adddress (auto display): $fill"
 else
  while [$loop = true]
  do
  echo -n "Search another patron? (y)es or (q)uit"
  read choice
  case $choice in
  y|Y) bash show_details;;
  q|Q) exit;;
  *) echo "Invalid input!"
  esac
  done
 fi
done

echo "$id"
```

Comment: A good resource to utilize is [shellcheck](https://www.shellcheck.net/) which can point out common syntax errors and other types of issues in shell scripts. Since you mentioned you're taking a class, you will probably be able to learn a lot from it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a number of problems with your code.

First, you're prompting for a patron id and storing that in the `id1` variable, but you **never use that variable anywhere else in your code**.

Second, this does nothing:

```
grep -i -q "$id" patron.txt
```

Even if you were using the correct variable, this command is effectively a no-op: it generates no output (because of the `-q`), and even if it did you're not doing anything with it. You're also ignoring the exit code.

This:

```
array=$(echo $id | tr ":" "\n")
```

Also does nothing useful: even if you were using the `id1` variable, you're just echoing the variable to `tr` and not making use of the contents of your `patron.txt` file.

Lastly, you probably want to use [`mapfile`](https://ss64.com/bash/mapfile.html) to populate your `array` variable.

---

Something like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "Search Patron Details"
echo -n "Enter Patron ID: "
read id1
mapfile -d: -t array < <(grep -i "$id1" patron.txt)

echo "Fullname (auto display): ${array[1]}"
echo "Contact Number (auto display): ${array[2]}"
echo "Email Adddress (auto display): ${array[3]}"
```

With your sample data in `patron.txt`, running this looks like:

```
Search Patron Details
Enter Patron ID: 123456
Fullname (auto display): Gerald
Contact Number (auto display): 010-9999999
Email Adddress (auto display): asdf@gmail.com
```

Comment: Thanks for the help! Firstly, for the id1, I was trying to get it to compare/match the first part of the array with id1, then when i grep'ed the info from the txt file it won't be seen and mess things up. And finally, I'm just going about things in the dark on the most part, my class hasn't taught tr's and mapfiles.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps using an **array** would make sense. You could do a

```
IFS=: read -a arr <patron.txt
```

This places the 4 components into an array `arr`, and you can access the individual parts by `${arr[0]}` .... `${arr[3]}`. You can also loop over it by

```
for fill in "${arr[@]}"
```

The quotes ensure that you don't get into trouble if your array fields one day contain spaces.